# How do you get the type of the generic from a reference?

Tags: c#, generics

I have a variable defined as:

```
Generate<IResource> generation = FindComponent<Generate<IResource>>();
```

Which finds the first component of this type.

But i need to now get the type of IResource from the variable `generation` so i know what resource is in use. But i am not sure how to obtain it from the variable. Is this possible?

Comment: Without us knowing any of the code of `Generate<T>` no it's impossible

Comment: Please show some sample inputs and outputs.

Comment: To use the duplicate, just replace `List<>` by `Generate<>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, the following would do, using the [Type.GetGenericArguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getgenericarguments?view=net-5.0) method:

```
generation.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0]);
```

[Check this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kchEWG)

```
using System;
            

public class Generate<IResource> {
}

public interface IResource {}
public class Resource: IResource {}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Generate<Resource> generation = new Generate<Resource>();
        Console.WriteLine(generation.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0]);
    }
}
```

Output: Resource

Comment: Weird i seem to get out of bounds error when accessing [0].

Comment: Returns an empty array if the current type is not a generic type.

Comment: Ah yeah thats why ! Just noticed heh! Thanks that seems to work ! :)